# How to receive the events from an ActionScript 1/2 swf in a flex swf?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, load

I was trying to load an flex-built swf into a swish-based movie and FAILing, doing some research led to:

> (AS1/AS2 and AS3) run in different
>   "virtual machines" within the Flash
>   Player. Like many product upgrades,
>   AS3 based SWF's can load AS1/2 based
>   SWF's but AS1/2 can not load an AS3
>   based SWF.
>
> ActionScript 3 is a totally new
>   product and not a simple upgrade of
>   AS2. Adobe made a "business" decision
>   to not include "legacy compatibility."

which comes from here: http://forums.swishzone.com/index.php?s=b8a808adb9b5dea0e88c5c6cedb97018&showtopic=60051&st=0&p=259340&#entry259340

One strategy I was told could be used is to create a swf that loads the AS 1/2 swf and then on some event loads my AS 3 movie.  Thing is, that event is in the AS 1/2 swf, so is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use LocalConnection calls for the two swfs to communicate, even within a parent swf. Grant Skinner wrote SWFBridge which may be useful to you: http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html.